# Small flag triangulations

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory, simplicial-complexes

In geometric group theory and low-dimensional topology, asking for a triangulation of a specific space to be flag can often be somewhat more cumbersome than just turning a CW-complex into a simplicial complex. Cheap ways to achieve this include taking successive barycentric subdivisions, which in practice makes the number of vertices and edges involved quite bloated.

For which properties of spaces (such as the properties of their fundamental group) are the smallest flag triangulations known?
Here, 'smallest' means one of 'vertex-minimal' or 'edge-minimal' (or 'triangle-minimal').

It would be useful to have a zoo of examples, for testing conjectures and quick computations. I expect that more may be known about this than appears at a first glance; since there could be various spaces or properties that this has been answered for, which only appear as small lemmas in literature focused on the applications, rather than the complexes themselves. On the other hand, there may be triangulations that we intuitively understand to be minimal, but rigorous proof may require heavy computation.

For example, in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.03303.pdf), vertex-minimal flag triangulations of several common spaces are found.

More specifically, I am wondering what the smallest flag complex with torsion-free perfect fundamental group is.

Comment: I don't know about smallest but one can easily construct flag triangulations of the presentation 2-complex of Higman's group. Also presentation 2-complexes of perfect small cancellation groups are fairly easy to construct and would guarantee non-trivial fundamental group.

Comment: I completely agree that a zoo of small examples would be very useful (though I don't see why the triangulations need to be provably minimal, as long as they are small enough to be tractable). One nice such "zoo" has been developed recently by Caprace--Conder--Kaluba--Witzel. The paper doesn't seem to be on the arXiv yet, but you can see a video of Caprace giving a talk about them here: https://www.newton.ac.uk/seminar/20200220160017002 .

Comment: In the direction of a zoo: it's sporadically updated, but have you seen http://www.eg-models.de/models_noapplet.html ?  It has many small triangulations of various nice spaces, with pictures + data.